# Ruby activerecord Outer Join of two tables with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I'm new to Ruby and Activer Record but I'm having a hard time with this question.
I have two tables:  tenants and apartments
Here are the definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE tenants(
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  age integer NOT NULL,
  gender varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  apartment_id integer NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE apartments(
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  address varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  monthly_rent decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
  sqft integer  NOT NUlL,
  num_beds integer NOT NULL,
  num_baths integer NOT NULL
);
```

The question I'm being asked is to:

*Iterate over each apartment, for each apartment, display it's address and all of it's tenants*

I went in psql and can find the answer with this query:
**select  a.address, b.name from apartments a, tenants b where a.id = b.apartment_id order by a.address;**

I can get iterate over each apartment, and then iterate over the tenants and find the answer this way but it is not too eligant and I still need a way to not print out the address if there are no matches on the inside loop.  Here is this code:

```
Apartment.find_each { |user|
   puts "-Outer Address #{user.address}"
   Tenant.find_each { | tenant|
    puts "-inner Tennant #{tenant.name}" if tenant.apartment_id==user.id
   } # tenant where
} #apartment.find
```

I'm sure there must be a method to call that will  put the two loops together, but I just cannot figure this one out..  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [includes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) to [eager load](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) associations and then loop through them:

```
Apartment.includes(:tenants).find_each do |apartment|
    apartment.tenants.each do |tenant|
        # print tenant details
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks!  Here is my modified code:``Apartment.includes(:tenants).find_each do |apartment|
    address_printed = true
    apartment.tenants.each do |tenant|
        # print tenant details
        puts "Address: #{apartment.address}" if address_printed
        puts " Tennant: #{tenant.name}"
        address_printed=false
    end
end``   I noticed you use do ends not {} Is this a style issue?

Comment: Ruby convention is to use {} for single line blocks and do..end for multi-line blocks.

Comment: In your code, you can move the `puts "Address: #{apartment.address}" ` outside of the inner loop and get rid of the `address_printed` check.